# Why does BasicService.getCodeBase() return null when using file:// as URL protocol in the JNLP codebase attribute?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

In a WebStart application, I'm using this code to retrieve programmatically the JNLP codebase:

```java
package web.start.test;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.jnlp.BasicService;
import javax.jnlp.ServiceManager;
import javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WebStartTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            BasicService basicService = (BasicService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");
            URL codeBase = basicService.getCodeBase();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Code base is: [" + codeBase + "]");
        }
        catch (UnavailableServiceException exception)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this JNLP descriptor to start the application:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:/d:/playground/eclipse/WebStartTest" href="WebStartTest.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>WebStartTest</title>
        <vendor>Web Start Tester</vendor>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" />
        <jar href="target/WebStartTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="web.start.test.WebStartTest" />
</jnlp>
```

After packaging and signing the jar file, hitting Enter on the JNLP file starts the application successfully, but the pop-up message says: **"Code base is: [null]"**.

The same code retrieves the codebase properly when deployed in a web server and launched via a JNLP file that uses "http://" instead of "file://" as the codebase protocol.

Is there a way to retrieve the codebase of a WebStart application when deployed on a local (or shared network) drive using a JNLP descriptor with a "file://" codebase?

If not, how else can I programmatically find the URL to the application directory in order to access resource files (that are not packaged within the jar files)?

Moreover, from a best practices standpoint: is deploying a WebStart application in a shared network drive rather than in a web server (for the sake of simplicity) a reasonable approach, or is it rather a hack that should be avoided?

Thank you.

Comment: I was working Applet and had same issue. When I run applet from local machine it was not working properly but when I uploaded applet jar on web server its working fine. I don't know why but may be its security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try deriving the application code base from the URL of a known class.

```
URL url = WebStartTest.class.getResource("/web/start/test/WebStartTest.class");

System.out.println("url = " + url);
```

prints

```
url = file:C:/projects/Test/classes/web/start/test/WebStartTest.class
```

Comment: Thank you, Keith, excellent suggestion!  The result needs a bit of parsing, but it certainly is a useful workaround.  Any suggestion as to whether getting 'null' is a bug in the WebStart framework, or rather a suggestion that "file:/" should not be used in JNLP codebases?

Comment: The javadoc for BasicService (at the class level) does have some language about it only working in offline mode-- though that leads me to think it would *only* work for offline, the opposite of what you are seeing.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html    So, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Because, sadly, that's the way it goes since Java 7 Update 25, as mentioned in its [Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html) regarding `Applet`s... and this would also appear to apply to `BasicService`:

> **Local Applets return NULL for codebase**
>
> Beginning with JDK 7u25, an applet's getCodeBase() method will
>   return NULL when the applet is running from the local file system.

Unfortunately, the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#getCodeBase%28%29) hasn't been updated to reflect this yet.

*And yes, using Web Start from a shared drived will make you enter a world of pain and I'd recommend you don't go down that route, as you'll have fun fighting sudden behavioral changes like this one, as well as caching issues and what not. Which is already painful for normal Web Start apps, but as you push to dark corners that they barely seem to test decently internally, I'd be afraid of hitting more and more issues. Not that I particularly dislike Web Start, but over the past 2 years many updates introduced pretty funky bugs.*

Comment: The Release Notes might only be referring to applets and not to WebStart (JNLP) applications, yet that remark does seem consistent with the WebStart framework also returning null when the app is run from a local drive or shared directory as opposed to via HTTP.  I agree with your recommendation and actually left out the shared drive JNLP option in our latest software version, but after several consultants complained about the extra complexity added to the deployment architecture by the requirement to include a web server, I started to feel like asking for second opinions on the topic.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndreiJuan: I'm wondering... if there's no need for a particular web server and it's not to deploy from a remote server but instead to share on a networked drive as a packaged app... why not package the whole thing as a single executable JAR or a similar solution?

Comment: @AndreiJuan: or, alternatively, as a solution copied and deployed on the networked drive, bundled with a startup script (windows batch or shell script, for instance) that would then bootstrap it. I'm asking, because that's actually something we're considering to do with one of our products, even though in our case Web Start makes perfect sense... but we're so fed up with the support and maintenance it occurs that we're considering going down that route.

Comment: Actually we do support installing that client as a stand-alone application on a shared drive, but creating a correct, secure and user-creativity-proof shared drive deployment ends up not being significantly easier than setting up a web server and deploying the WebStart client in it.  And in itself the WebStart client works just great, except when someone thinks: hey, why don't I just drop this web distribution thing in a shared drive and skip the web server part? :)

Comment: @AndreiJuan: I feel your pain. :)

Answer (score -1):

Could it be because you are using 'file:/' instead of 'file://' ?

Comment: No, as tempting and natural as using two slashes may seem, that doesn't actually work at all, you get: com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: file://c/...